# Do APEX Regex patterns support named groups?

Tags: regular-expressions

Do apex regular expressions support named groups? Similar to http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#group%28java.lang.String%29?

Example `(?<name>X)`

The syntax seems to be supported but I couldn't find a way to reference groups by name: https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_classes_pattern_and_matcher_matcher_methods.htm

`Pattern oTestPattern = Pattern.compile('(?<name>X)');
Matcher oMatcher = oTestPattern.matcher('X');
System.assert(false, oMatcher.groupCount());`

Answer (score 2):

Currently, as at Spring 15, the answer is no, you can't access the named groups in a [Matcher](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_classes_pattern_and_matcher_matcher_methods.htm) even though they are valid in the RegEx.

There isn't a method exposed to access the capture group by name. There is [`group(Integer)`](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_classes_pattern_and_matcher_matcher_methods.htm#apex_System_Matcher_group_2) to get the capture group by groupIndex. Note that group zero always stands for the entire expression.

If you try and call `group(String)` you will get an error

> Method does not exist or incorrect signature: [Matcher].group(String) line:X

See also:

- [Understanding Capturing Groups](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_classes_pattern_and_matcher_capturing_groups.htm)